# Angularjs binding calculation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, math, ionic-framework, calculus

How can i calculate the sum of some scopes and rest the sum of other scopes with 30% discount?:

```
{{(data.a * 30) + (data.b * 10) + data.c - [(data.d * 5)+(data.e * 0.75)] * 30 / 100}}
```

I tried this and it's not working:

```
{{data.dominio + data.alojamiento + data.logotipo + data.pagespeed + (data.categoriasblog * 10) + (data.entradasblog * 10) + data.mapa + data.soporte + data.seo + data.multi + (data.cattien50 * 10) + (data.cattien200 * 10) + (data.cattien600 * 8) + (data.cattien5000 * 2) + (data.prodtien50 * 2) + (data.prodtien200 * 2) + (data.prodtien600 * 2)  + (data.prodtien5000 * 0.50) + (data.metpag50 * 5) + (data.metpag200 * 5) + (data.metpag600 * 2) + (data.metpag2000 * 0.75) + (data.metpag5000 * 0.5) + (data.metenv50 * 5) + (data.metenv200 * 5) + (data.metenv600 * 4) + (data.metenv2000 * 3) + (data.metenv5000 * 2) + data.pesoydim50 +  data.pesoydim200 + data.pesoydim600 + data.pesoydim2000 + data.pesoydim5000 + data.tpv50 + data.tpv200 + data.tpv600 + data.tpv2000 + data.tpv5000 - (data.cattien2000 * 5) - (data.prodtien2000 * 0.75) * 0.30}}
```

The project is posted here: https://creator.ionic.io/share/html/2d9b0126751e#/menu/tienda

The scenario is:

U need to choose from the dropdown "Tipo de tienda" -> De 601 - 2000 productos
Select the number of the categories and products and on the bottom i have to apply a 30% discount based of the cost of those products and categories.

On the final step i have a resume, wich calculates all the values and should discount the 30% if the user has a .csv file with those products.

Comment: This description is not enough to go on.  Please provide more details on the problems you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{

((data.a * 30) + (data.b * 10) + data.c - (data.d * 5)-(data.e * 0.75)) * 0.30

}}
```

Comment: Thanks but i have to calculate two parts like:

Comment: {{

((data.a * 30) + (data.b * 10) + data.c +  (data.d * 5)) - ((data.e * 0.75) + (data.f * 0.75) * 30 / 100)

}}

Comment: I need to get 30% discount from the second block, it's not working, somehow a get a result like 0001281821821882.198178271828121

Answer (score 0):

`[ ]` is for arrays. If you need double parenthesis just use... `( )` two times!

```
{{(data.a * 30) + (data.b * 10) + data.c - ((data.d * 5) + (data.e * 0.75)) * 30 / 100}}
```

**[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mf2uvsfL/)** on JSFiddle.